# Showing overlay in wrong geo point using Open Street Map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using the osmdroid-android 3.0.5.jar instead of Google map api to show the location in map by using geo-coordinate.

Well i am able to get map in android emulator but the problem is the overlay i am using to point to location is wrong.

Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private MapView osmMapView;
private MapController controller;
private Projection projection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    osmMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.osm_map_view);

    this.osmMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    this.osmMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    this.osmMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    this.projection = this.osmMapView.getProjection();

    this.controller = this.osmMapView.getController();
    this.controller.setZoom(5);

    List<Overlay> overLayList = osmMapView.getOverlays();
    overLayList.add(new ScaleBarOverlay(this));
    overLayList.add(new PutOverLayOnMap(this));
}

private class PutOverLayOnMap extends Overlay {
    public PutOverLayOnMap(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    protected void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        Point point = new Point();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(41.057121 * 1E6), (int)(-73.561867 * 1E6));
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
        c.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, paint);
        System.out.println("GeoPoint(OSM) : "+geoPoint.getLatitudeE6()+" #### "+geoPoint.getLongitudeE6());

    }
}
```

The following is my main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/osm_map_view"
    renderer="CloudMadeStandardTiles"
    cloudmadeStyle="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I am using

```
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(41.057121 * 1E6), (int)(-73.561867 * 1E6));
```

which is the geo-coordinate of **Stamford US** Now the red dot is showing somewhere Africa, center of the map (intersection of latitude & longitude).

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the projection in the draw method. The javadocs for getProjection tell you

*public MapView.Projection getProjection()
Get a projection for converting between screen-pixel coordinates and latitude/longitude coordinates. You should not hold on to this object for more than one draw, since the projection of the map could change.*

So in your draw method, insert the line as shown below

```
....
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
Point point = new Point();
projection = osmMapView.getProjection(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ADD THIS LINE
GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (41.057121 * 1E6),
                        (int) (-73.561867 * 1E6));
projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
.....
```

This should fix it.